# Intent Filter for opening up only the browser android

Tags: android, intentfilter

My app has an activity with the following intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:host="m.testsite.com"> </data>
            <data android:scheme="http"></data>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*"></data>
 </intent-filter>
```

This opens up any link with the url http://m.testsite.com/anypath  in the app . However sometimes it so happens that there is no data inside the app with respect to the path and I need to transfer him back to the browser only.

What should be the intent-filter for this?

Edit:-Seems like my question was not very clear .The device had two packages listening to the same intent-filter. One was the browser and the other was my app. I was in a situation where in certain cases, I had to target only the browser and not the app for the same intent-filter. I was hoping that there would be some particular action or category which I could target for just the browser alone. However I managed to solve it . I have put my answer below.

Comment: What exactly is your question? The intent to open the browser? Or how to change the pathPattern to make sure it only captures 'valid' URLs?

Comment: I want to target only the browser and not my own app for the same url

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you want an updated pathPattern so some URL's don't go to your app, but only on the browser? In that case, we need more info. What URLs don't need to be in the intent-filter which currently are?

Comment: @fifarunnerr Look at the solution below and my edit. If you still dont understand it , just stay away or hire a scribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it finally:-

```
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
     if (!activityName.contains("MyApplicationActivity")) {
                   browserIntent =
                           packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
                    ComponentName comp =
                            new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

                    browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                    browserIntent.setComponent(comp);
                    browserIntent.setData(data);
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                    break;
                }}
```